# Why does my program reach a Segmentation fault? Am I using to much memory on the stack?

Tags: c, memory-management, simulation

I cant  seem to debug my program any further. Sometimes it completes without any problems, and sometimes i get an segmentation fault after a while (at random points). Im guessing that i am using to much memory on the stack with my `char* nbateams[]` array. I proboly should malloc some memory on the heap for it instead. Or what do you think? If that is the case, how much memory do i need to allocate?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

// constants for teams in the leauge, max points and minimum points.
#define MAXTEAMS 30
#define MAX_P 110
#define MIN_P 70

//structure for the "gameday"
struct gameday
{
    char* team;
    int points;
};

// prototypes
int scoreGenerator();
int teamGenerator();
void anouncement(int n);

int main(void)
{
    // all the teams. +1 to reserve space for null character
    char* nbateams[MAXTEAMS+1] = {"Brooklyn Nets", "New York Knicks", "Philadelphia 76ers", "Toronto Raptors", "Boston Celtics",
                                  "Chicago Bulls", "Cleveland Cavaliers", "Detroit Pistons", "Indiana Pacers", "Milwaukee Bucks",
                                  "Atlanta Hawks", "Charlotte Hornets", "Miami Heat", "Orlando Magic", "Washington Wizards",
                                  "Denver Nuggets", "Minnesota Timberwolves", "Oklahoma City Thunder", "Portland Trail Blazers", "Utah Jazz",
                                  "Golden State Warriors, Los Angeles Clippers, Los Angeles Lakers, Phoenix Suns, Sacramento Kings",
                                  "Dallas Mavericks", "Houston Rockets", "Memphis Grizzlies", "New Orleans Pelicans", "San Antonio Spurs"};

    // how many games do you want to be played? 
    int nbagames = 0;

    while(nbagames < 10)
    {
        // gets the first team and generates a score for it
        struct gameday team1;
        team1.team = nbateams[TeamGenerator()];
        team1.points = ScoreGenerator(team1.team);

        // gets a second team and generates score for it. Keep generating untill the teams are not the same
        struct gameday team2;
        do
        { 
            team2.team = nbateams[TeamGenerator()];

        } while(strcmp(team1.team, team2.team) == 0);

        // gets points for team2 untill they are not equal to team1s points.
        do
        { 
            team2.points = ScoreGenerator(team2.team);

        } while(team1.points == team2.points);

        // prints out the diffrent teams and their points
        printf("\n");
        printf("%s(%d) - %s(%d)\n", team1.team, team1.points, team2.team, team2.points);


        // get data for anouncement, so we can print out the winner and such.
        int n = 0;
        if (team1.points > team2.points)
        {
            n = team1.points - team2.points;
            printf("The %s ", team1.team);
            anouncement(n);
        }
        else
        {
            n = team2.points - team1.points;
            printf("The %s ", team2.team);
            anouncement(n);
        }
        printf("\n");
        // increment the nba games played.
        nbagames++;
    }
}
// get psudorandom score based on the time and the leanght of the team name.
int scoreGenerator(char* team)
{
    srand(time(NULL) + strlen(team));

    int score = rand() % (MAX_P  - MIN_P + 1) + MIN_P;

    return score;
}
// get psudorandom team.
int teamGenerator(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int r = rand() % MAXTEAMS-1;

    return r;
}
// print out an extra message dependent on how much the team won the game with.
void anouncement(int n)
{
    if(n <= 5)
        printf("win the close game");
    else if(n <= 15)
        printf("win the game");
    else
        printf("win the blowout game");
}
```

EDIT: I think i found my stupid error... In my array I had some missing quotation marks.

Comment: Use memory debugger such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: `nbateams` has 26 Team, not `MAXTEAMS+1`. So `nbateams[TeamGenerator()];` become `NULL`.

Comment: you should call `srand(time(NULL));` only once in your program, otherwise `teamGenerator()` would return the same number in the same second.

Answer (score 0):

BLUEPIXY and mch said is right. and there is another bug.

```
int r = rand() % MAXTEAMS-1;
```

The r value may be -1. because rand()%MAXTEAMS maybe zero, then it sub 1, you got an -1.